# corrupt main function stack

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I have the following C code:

```
int main()
{
    char s[10];

    scanf("%s", s);
}
```

**EDIT:** assembly generated for the upper C program is the following:

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
sub    $0x10,%rsp
lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
mov    %rax,%rsi
mov    $0x4005e4,%edi
mov    $0x0,%eax
callq  400420 <__isoc99_scanf@plt>
leaveq
retq
```

If the user enters more than the size of the array, it will result in overwriting other stack values. Looking at the assembly generated, I find that gcc lowers the stack pointer by 16 bytes instead of 10(word alignment). So, if I enter more than 16 bytes the stack should corrupt and on return of main it should likely just segfault.

Interesting this behaviour does happen but it happens if I enter a lot of characters. Any reason why it doesn't fail at 17 characters?

Comment: Can you post the assembly?

Comment: yeah...  I'm voting to close as there's no value in having yet another SO question to which the answer is the two words, "undefined behavior."

Comment: A little more than just "undefined behavior" - it depends highly on the platform and compiler you use. The pertinent question is, "what is living in the memory immediately after the end of my array, and how critical is that stuff to the operation of the program". Depending on the answer to that, you may crash (stack structure, or return addresses smashed), see nothing (empty space or variables that are never referenced), or ....

Comment: "undefined behavior" isn't the reason it doesn't fail as he expects, it's the reason he shouldn't care. If the OP posts the assembler (as I've requested), I can probably tell him what's going on. It's environment specific, and not very useful, but the OP seems to have at least a basic (if generic) understanding of buffer overflow, but in this case it's not working exactly as he expects.

Comment: Exactly how many input characters does it take to crash your program?

Comment: @jimhark Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @jimhark exactly 24 characters

Comment: @mc_87, that's what I thought.

Comment: @Aniket, yup you're right, it's Undefined Behavior. Which, of course, is different from Unexplainable Behavior. There are a variety of reasons why someone might want to understand exactly what's going on. For example someone writing buffer overflow tests for a specific environment might find the details useful, as would anyone trying to understand exactly how a buffer overflow is exploited as a security flaw.

Comment: what is to explain why it only takes 24 characters and not more? On my system it takes 12 characters. It depends on the DATA-CODE boundary and compiler specific.. sometimes it is environment specific. If you cross from data boundary to code boundary, IntelArchitecture raises Segmentation violation error(and generates an interrupt) a SEGMENTATION VIOLATION SIGNAL(SIGSEGV) reaches the program from the kernel, aborting the program completely, with a coredump

Comment: @Aniket, you've convinced me the explanation of "why" is not useful to you. I've tried to explain that it might be useful to mc_87, or others. Turns out mc-87 *is* using a specific compiler, so I was able to answer his question. He wants to understand buffer overflows. He looked at the assembler, hypothesised a failure mode, but his tests didn't match. He wanted to know why. He was close and I hoped to help him bridge the gap. That's why I wrote my explanation.

Comment: @jimhark I appreciate your concern and urge to answer a question precisely. For which I've already +1d you

Comment: @Aniket, you're right I misread your last comment. Sorry. It takes exactly 24 characters on the OP's system because it's 64-bit. His 10 byte buffer is rounded up to 16 bytes and the BP is 8 bytes. On a 32-bit system the buffer would round up to 12 bytes (next multiple of 4) and the BP would be 4 bytes. So either the compiler is optimizing out pushing the BP (maybe a no-frame optimization) or the run-time is referencing a local var on return. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual behavior revolves around the details of how memory is allocated on the stack (which is implementation dependent, leading to undefined behavior). Let's say when your code is entered (called) the stack offset is 0 at that point and what RSP is pointing tois the return address.

If you take a quick look at the assembler this might jump out at you:

```
sub    $0x10,%rsp
```

This reserves space for your local variables, and you were expecting this. It's easy to think these 16 bytes are the only stack space we're reserving. And if we go past that, we'll be overwriting the return value and crashing the process (or at least the thread).

Because it's easy to miss the first instruction:

```
push   %rbp
```

Saves the base pointer as part of the calling convention (so the call stack can be traced), and takes up an additional 8 bytes (for 64-bit architecture, ebp is only 4 bytes on 32-bit). So you have 24 bytes before you start to overwrite the return address. And remember if you enter 24 characters, a terminating null ('\0') will be stored as the 25th character, and that's the one that will corrupt the return address.

And while the base pointer stored on the stack is also overwritten, it's not used in `main` after that. But note the caller will be messed up because:

```
leaveq
```

Will set RSP to RBP, then POP RBP. So if the caller references local variables after the call returns, there will likely be a problem. If the caller were different (if you were using a different run-time), writing to that 17th character might have been a problem (possibly causing a SEGFAULT in the caller).

Comment: Ok, got it. Even though the rbp gets corrupted the stack pointer doesnt. Had the _start which calls main function accessed the local variables after main return, even on 17 character the program should have resulted in UB behaviour. right?

Comment: First you hit undefined behavior as soon as you do the out of range array access. What happens to happen in your environment (current version, this could change). In this case, you're right. The caller will be using a bad pointer to access local vars. I'm updating my answer to add this.

Answer (score 0):

The program is going to act flakey if you overwrite the stack. The particular compiler is going to format the stack in its own internally defined way.

The way to avoid this is to use something that reads in a way that limits the number of input chars to the size of the buffer.

One way is to add the length into the format `"%9s"` leaving room for the end of string character.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code will get a segfault not for overwriting the end of your buffer, but for accessing memory that isn't present in the system [or trying to write to memory that is read-only, but that's less likely in this case]. So this won't happen until your code returns from main - unless the string is so long it exceeds highest address available on the stack - which is most likely several hundred bytes, if not more than that. [Of course, no input at all happens until you hit enter, either - up to that point, the input is just held in the buffer for `stdin`]

Second, it's called "undefined behaviour" (UB for short) meaning that it's not defined what happens. So, you can't expect any particular behaviour to be CERTAIN - it may well work differently to what you expect. UB is unpredictable, and can in some circumstances appear to work perfectly fine [because what you just overwrote, or otherwise 'abused' doesn't actually get used in some way that is critical enough to cause a crash - but the invoice sent to the customer now has a very huge dollar value on it... ;)